# debugging redis db with TTL on some keys

Tags: redis

I have a .rdb file from Redis, which contains keys with TTL. The rdb file is quite old, I would like to examinate contents in order to debug my application. However, when loading the .rdb file in Redis keys are automatically removed because of expiration.

Is there a way to tell redis to ignore expiration ? So I can look at keys to do my debugging without having those removed...

Maybe it's possible by changing my computer time and date but I would really want to avoid this.

Any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this tool: https://github.com/sripathikrishnan/redis-rdb-tools

It allows to read a .rdb file, to emit contents as Redis protocol. The `-x` option do not set TTL on keys. Using `redis-cli --pipe`, it is possible to populate a fresh redis instance with all contents from the .rdb file:

```
rdb -c protocol rdb_file_to_debug.rdb -x | redis-cli --pipe
```